# Find all *.xml.err files with certain content in certain directory and need to move the *.xml files to its parent directory and remove *.xml.err files

Tags: find, rm, mv

I am trying to compose a Linux shell command but stuck here.

Here is the background:

The system will generate *.xml and *.xml.error correspondingly under */tmp/A/processed*，*/tmp/A/not_processed*，*/tmp/B/processed*，*/tmp/B/not_processed* directories. The overall directories are uncertain. For example */tmp/C* */tmp/D*...

I need to find all *.xml.err files with content "oracle" under */tmp/A/not_processed* and */tmp/B/not_processed*. Then need to move the *.xml files to its parent directory which is */tmp/A* or */tmp/B* and remove *.xml.err files.

Here is the code which should be fine:

```
find /home/tmp  -name \*.err -type f -path "*not_processed*" -execdir grep -l -i "oracle" {} \; -execdir sh -c '
    for name do
        mv "${name%.*}" ".."
        rm -rf  "$name"
    done' sh {} +
```

I am trying to optimize the performance by dropping the -for loop by using multiple -execdir parameters of find.

```
find /home/tmp  -name \*.err -type f -path "*not_processed*" -execdir grep -l -i "oracle" {} \; -execdir mv {} .. \; -execdir rm -rf {} \;
```

However, I was stuck that `-execdir mv {} .. \;` I couldn't drop the second extension name `.err`. {} should be the array with file paths such as `./a.xml.err ./b.xml.err`. I tried to simply add `.err` behind the {}, that is `-execdir mv {}.err .. \;` I can get `./a.xml.err.err ./b.xml.err.err`. Now I know how to add `.err` extension but stuck in dropping `.err` extension for the {}.

Thank you in advance and your efforts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're forking a new shell for each and every file.

You might gain some performance by instead (properly) piping `find`'s output to a `read` loop and operating within it.

Orherwise I'm afraid crawling crowded tree structures is expensive and moreover, this sounds like you'll accumulate other `.err` files that'll only keep increasing the number of files to grep.

All in all, the best performance improvement you'll find is fixing the app that generates the original problem.